# SQL Paging on more than 10 lac Records

Tags: asp.net, sql, optimization, paging

I am using MS SQL 2008 R2. One of my table have more than 10 *lac* rows — 1 *lac* is 10<sup>5</sup> or 100,000, so 10 *lac* is 1,000,000).

I want to bind this to ASP Gridview. I tried custom paging with page size and index. But grid not binded. Timeout Error occured.

Tried directly execute stored procedure, but it takes a long time.

How can I optimize this procedure ?

My procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_LOAN_APPROVAL_GET_LIST

  @USERCODE NVARCHAR(50) ,
  @FROMDATE DATETIME     = NULL ,
  @TODATE   DATETIME     = NULL ,
  @PAGESIZE INT          ,
  @PAGENO   INT          ,
  @TOTALROW BIGINT       OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

  SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT DOC_NO       ,
                DOC_DATE_GRE ,
                EMP_CODE     ,
                EMP_NAME_ENG as Name ,
                LOAN_AMOUNT  ,
                DESC_ENG     as Discription ,
                REMARKS      ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                  ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 )
                  ) AS [ROWNO]
         from VW_PER_LOAN
         Where isnull( POST_FLAG   , 'N' )  = 'N'
           and ISNULl( CANCEL_FLAG , 'N' ) != 'Y'
           and DOC_DATE_GRE between ISNULL(@FROMDATE , DOC_DATE_GRE )
                                and ISNULL(@TODATE   , DOC_DATE_GRE )
           and  BRANCH in ( SELECT *
                            FROM DBO.FN_SSP_GetAllowedBranches(@USERCODE)
                          )
       ) T
  WHERE T.ROWNO BETWEEN ((@PAGENO-1)*@PAGESIZE)+1 AND @PAGESIZE*(@PAGENO)

  SELECT @TOTALROW=COUNT(*)
  from VW_PER_LOAN
  Where isnull(POST_FLAG,'N')= 'N'
    and ISNULl(CANCEL_FLAG,'N')!='Y'
    and DOC_DATE_GRE between ISNULL(@FROMDATE,DOC_DATE_GRE)and ISNULL(@TODATE,DOC_DATE_GRE)
    and BRANCH in ( SELECT *
                    FROM DBO.FN_SSP_GetAllowedBranches(@USERCODE)
                  )

END
```

Thanks

Comment: This is error 
"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to look at your *execution plan* and discuss it with a DBA if you don't understand it.

The obvious thing that stands out is that your `where` clause has pretty much every column reference wrapped in some sort of function. That makes them *expressions* and make the SQL optimizer unable to use any covering indices that might exist.

It looks like you are calling a table-valued function as an uncorrelated subquery. That would worry me with respect to performance. I'd probably move that out of the query. Instead run it just once and populate a temporary table.